# Sum of geodesic deviation around a triangle in curved spacetime?

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, geodesics, relative-motion

So I was pondering about geodesic deviations and I'm confused about the following. Let's say I have $3$ geodesics $\gamma_1(t)$ , $\gamma_2(t)$ and $\gamma_3(t)$. I introduce a parameter $s$ such that $\gamma_{ij}(t,s)$ obeys:

$$ \gamma_{12}(t,0)  = \gamma_1$$
$$ \gamma_{12}(t,1) = \gamma_2$$
$$ \gamma_{23}(t,0) = \gamma_2$$
$$ \gamma_{23}(t,1)  = \gamma_3$$
$$ \gamma_{31}(t,0)  = \gamma_3$$
$$ \gamma_{31}(t,1)  = \gamma_1$$

Now, I know in the geodesic deviation $\zeta^\mu_{ij}$ between $\gamma_i$ and $\gamma_j$. In  a flat spacetime intuitively I imagine the relation locally:

$$ \zeta^\mu_{12} + \zeta^\mu_{23} + \zeta^\mu_{31} = 0 $$

Similarly the relative velocities obey when summed around in a triangle obey:

How does this get modified in curved spacetime?

In other words, For each pair of $\gamma_i,\gamma_j$ I pick a congruence they're part of and get a deviation vector field $\zeta^\mu_{ij}$ on the inside of the triangle. Now I ask asking what happens when you sum these three vector fields in curved space time?

Comment: You may as well simplify your equations, e.g. the first becomes $\gamma_{12}(t,\,0)=\gamma_1$.

Comment: there is a bunch of mixed notation above and I cannot really read this.

However, for this problem, my suggestion would be "do this on a globe with your three vertices being "the intersection of the prime meridian and the equator, (90 degrees west, 0 N), and the north pole", comparing the embedding in 3-d space to the geodesics along the globe.

Comment: or alternately, your comparison point could be "the triangle in "Euclidean lat-long space"", though that is a bit artificial for such a concrete problem.